# How to extract whole html with complete styling after when user designed their page on my website?

Tags: html, extract

Like weeebly, Wix i want to make a website on which user can be able to design their web page with predefined controls and styling. So how can i get or extract whole web page's html with complete styling ? please mention any link or solution

Answer (score 0):

If you are using linux or mac, then I'd suggest using [wget](https://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html).  As long as the website isn't blocking these types of download requests wget will download the entire website including resource files (-r) and create the folder structure that would make sense.

```
wget -r -p -e robots=off http://www.example.com
```

If the url you want to retrieve blocks this sort of download request, you'll then only receive the index.html using wget.

On windows I use https://www.httrack.com/ It's free and downloads the website just fine.  Believe someone has created a windows version of wget as well.

Comment: i want building a web builder platform like www.Wix.com, weebly. so  i want to extract whole html and styling (css) using code. now by any external applicaion